# Is there any symfony2 tutorail for complex web application

Tags: php, symfony

I have to develop complex web application in symfony 2 where i have 20 database entites and many to many relationships.

I am experienced programmer but i am new to this symfony and OOP.

Is there any tutorial where i i can see many entitties and repositories and thier relationship as an example to start with

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any very complex tutorials of Symfony2 yet made to the public, but here are some good ones that helped me start out when I was first learning Symfony2:

1) Symblog: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/

2) Jobeet: http://sftuts.com/doc/jobeet/en/starting-up-the-project

But I probably learned the most from just reading over the thorough the book/cookbook available on the symfony2 website: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html

Symfony2 is strictly object oriented, so you might want to read up on OOP as well if you're new to the concept.

Answer (score 1):

[KnpBundles.com](http://www.knpbundles.com) is rather complex and available on [github](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpBundles).

[LilaConceptsBestPracticeBundle](https://github.com/LilaConcepts/LilaConceptsBestPracticeBundle) is another great bundle showing Symfony 2.1 best practices (covering integration with Travis CI, Code styles fixer, Composer, etc).

I highly recommend these for everybody who is looking for best-practices (like me). :)